# Bash config file throwing errors when sourced from Perl script

Tags: bash, perl

Got a line of perl that calls a bash wrapper function after it sources `.bash_profile`

`system ('source ~/.bash_profile; osascript -e \'quit app "Chromium"\'');`

Although the wrapper function gets called and is executed perfectly fine, I'm getting an error thrown from an unrelated bash function:

```
/Users/me/.bashrc: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/Users/me/.bashrc: line 9: `  done < <(find -L "$1" -type f -not -name *.swp -print0 | LC_COLLATE=C sort -dz)'
```

This is the problem function in the `.bashrc` file:

```
source_dir() {
  while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
    source_file "$file"
  done < <(find -L "$1" -type f -not -name *.swp -print0 | LC_COLLATE=C sort -dz)
}
```

This bash function does not throw errors when sourcing it directly, only when loading it through the Perl script. I'm curious to know why.

I'm running bash version 5.0.2.

Comment: osacript doesn't matter. It's  just a bash wrapper to the system's 'osascript' command. It is getting called and works as intended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

perl's `system` uses `/bin/sh` as the shell (https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html). It won't understand bash-specific syntax such as process substitutions.

You'll want to explicitly invoke bash:

```
system 'bash', '-c', q{source ~/.bash_profile; osascript -e 'quit app "Chromium"'};
```

Using the `q{}` single-quoting mechanism to avoid backslashing.

---

A bash note: if you invoke it as an interactive shell, it slurps in the bashrc automatically, so you should be able to do:

```
system 'bash', '-ic', q{osascript -e 'quit app "Chromium"'};
```

ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files

Comment: Thanks. And this has uncovered a blind spot of mine. I'm not sure exactly what the difference is between `sh` and `bash`. This helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash

Comment: @StevieD  But please check `ls -l /bin/sh`; normally `/bin/sh` is merely a link to another shell, and that's most often `bash`.  However, I find that invoking `sh` (from a terminal for instance) comes with differences -- perhaps it doesn't run initialization, even though it really runs `bash`. In this case that would be why explicit `bash` (what always should be done of course) solves your problem.

Comment: On Mac's, `/bin/sh` goes to `Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64`

Comment: I always thought they were the same as well. The link I provided above points out the differences.

Comment: @StevieD They aren't  the same and the link you found is good and very useful.  I meant to say that these days (I think) the `sh` on Linux is really a copy of bash (or dash).  Good to see what it is on Mac.

Comment: @zdim Invoking bash with `sh` makes it run in [POSIX mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html). It does read the startup files, though.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Well, alright; thanks for clarifying that. I looked through the differences -- it's a bit of a mess I'd say: they're mostly subtle but of consequence (but don't make it behave like `sh` either). Reads to me like a warning: don't do this; surprises live here.